# Unable to understand zsh error while executing rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, zsh

When I execute `%rake college:create[demo]`, I get the following error,

```
zsh: no matches found: college:create[demo]
```

Anybody has a solution for this?

when I execute `rake -T`, this is what I get when as one of the lines of the output:

```
rake college:create[config_name]            # create a college profile
```

So, it is a valid command, but still zsh shows the error.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try with:

```
rake college:create\[demo\]
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use noglob

```
noglob rake college:create[demo]
```

or just alias it in your .zshrc

```
alias rake='noglob rake'
```

Comment: Do you know how to solve it when using the bundle plugin for zsh? this alias is not enough.

Comment: sorry, got it: `alias rake="noglob bundled_rake"`

Answer (score 7):

`zsh` is trying to interpret your command as a wildcard file specication. `college:create[demo]` will expand to the list of existing files that match one of:

```
college:created
college:createe
college:createm
college:createo
```

[This page](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/globbing-wildcard-characters-with-zsh/6140012) shows some of the wildcarding that `zsh` performs, the specific example in this case being:

> - the [123] specifier, which indicates any of the characters 1, 2, or 3.

You need to escape the argument so that `zsh` doesn't think you're giving it a wildcard, such as with:

```
rake 'college:create[demo]'
```

The [manpage for zshexpn](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn) shows all the expansions done on command lines in *great* detail. Search for `Filename Generation` for the `xyzzy[demo]` style generations.

Comment: thnx!..I din know that zsh intrepreted ':' as wildcard:-)

Comment: @user966265 it is not the `:`, it is the brackets that are interpreted as wildcard; the colon has special meaning in a couple of substitutions: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html (search for "colon")

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rake via `bundle exec` or from `bin/` dir add this to you .zshrc file:

```
alias bin/rake='noglob rake'
# or 
alias rake="noglob bundled_rake
```